# Sculpting problem clipping on model

Tags: sculpting

[image]
new to blender and sculpting how do i fix the uneven part? it seems to be clipping

Comment: It seems like two objects/meshes overlapping each other to me. Or maybe your mesh has duplicate geometry.

Answer (score 5):

You should remesh your character: press Shift R, move the mouse to set a resolution grid, confirm with left mouse button then press Ctrl R to execute the Remesh function.

[image]